# Override style of a specific dataItem

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am working on my first Windows 8 RT application and started with the sample grid application. My goal is to change the style of one of these grid items.

I have been able to 'find' this item by using this:

```
if (dataItem.UniqueId.StartsWith("Group-1-Item-1"))
```

Then I created this style in C# (just as an example);

```
Style style = new Style (typeof(SampleDataItem));
Thickness thick = new Thickness(4,4,4,4);
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(100)));
```

However, now I have to apply this style to the specific data item - I have tried a lot of things, but I don't take they make much sense now that I look at them.

Comment: Are you just experimenting at this point, or do you have a specific criteria in mind that you're planning to use as the basis for a given item having a different style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data template for the dataItems for the Grid App project template is found in StandardStyles.xaml, and is referred to by the key "Standard250x250ItemTemplate".

If the idea is to vary the styling based on the content of the item, one approach might be to use a Binding.Converter, [as shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter.aspx), to convert the value of the content in question to the desired style or style property.

For example, If I wanted to make any items in the default Grid App template have a green background if the item number was less than or equal to 3, and red if it was higher than 3, I would create the following converter class (in my case, I just added the class to the GroupedItemsPage.xaml.cs, just before the GroupedItemsPage partial class):

```
// Custom class implements the IValueConverter interface.
public class StyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    // Define the Convert method to change a title ending with > 3 
    // to a red background, otherwise, green.
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        // The value parameter is the data from the source object.
        string title = (string)value;
        int lastNum = (int.Parse(title.Substring(title.Length - 1)));
        if (lastNum > 3)
        {
            return "Red";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Green";
        }
    }

    // ConvertBack is not implemented for a OneWay binding.
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Once the class is defined, along with the desired Convert method, I add an instance to it in my App.xaml file, so it will be available to the item template in StandardStyles.xaml:

```
<!-- Application-specific resources -->
<local:StyleConverter x:Key="StyleConverter"/>
```

In StandardStyles.xaml, I made a copy of the Standard250x250ItemTemplate that binds from the Title property of the item, to my converter class, like so:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Standard250x250ItemTemplate_Convert">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
        <Border Background="{Binding Title, 
             Converter={StaticResource StyleConverter}}">
        </Border>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

the key piece being the binding of the Border element's Background property to the Title, with the Converter={StaticResource StyleConverter}, which wires the item template up to my converter. Note that in addition to binding the Background property, I also removed the nested Image element from the original version of the item template.

Finally, in GroupedItemsPage.xaml, I change the item template to my customized version:

```
<!-- Horizontal scrolling grid used in most view states -->
<GridView
    x:Name="itemGridView"
    ...
    Padding="116,137,40,46"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate_Convert}"
    ...
    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
```

Once that's done, I can run the project, and here's what I see:

[image: Grid App with Converter]

Hope that helps!

For more info on Windows Store app development, register for [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer _devhammer_! It really helped me out and I was able to implement this as your proposed. Also it helped me understand more about data binding, something that I did not quiet understand yet.

I am left with a small question that perhaps you could also be of assistance. My idea was to apply a background image to some of the tiles, and I was able to do that by using a directory link instead of red/green. Unfortunately, the tile image is not very sharp because of the use of .png/.jpg. Is it possible to use a xaml vector shape as background image? Thank you again!

Comment: Glad I could help. As regards using a XAML shape as the background, I think you should be able to do that...just replace the embedded Image element with your desired XAML, nested in the Border element tags. Give it a try...I'm not as deep on XAML as I am with HTML, but I think that should work. Good luck!